# Why isn't .prop("selected",true) not working when .attr() or .addClass() does?

Tags: jquery, html-select, prop

I have a script that replaces a select box with a set of styled divs by hiding the select box and targeting it when the user clicks a "fake" div. I'm targeting the selected item like this:

```
targetSelect.eq(optionIndex).prop('selected');
```

`optionIndex` is the index of the selected div as it corresponds to the hidden select box option.

The above line does not add "selected" to the target option. I know I'm targeting the correct one since `targetSelect.eq(optionIndex).addClass('selected');` will add that class and `targetSelect.eq(optionIndex).attr('selected',"true");` sets a selected attribute to true.

I've also tried:

```
targetSelect.prop('selectedIndex',optionIndex);
```

but that doesn't work either.

Comment: what does `targetSelect` set for?

Comment: what is targetSelect ? can you provide a jsfiddle ?

Comment: `.prop` sets a property, it doesn't set an attribute.

Comment: selected should be set with .prop

Comment: Is `targetSelect.eq(optionIndex).prop('selected', true);` what you want to do?
because your code just reads the `prop`, not writing it...

Comment: @JasonP I'm not trying to set the attr. That was just given to show I'm targeting the correct item.

Comment: @Dimitri - targetSelect is just me storying the `("select option")` of the targeting select box

Answer (score 4):

I believe this should work:

```
$('#selectbox option').eq(optionIndex).prop('selected', true);
```

You could also try this (make sure the optionIndex is not a string!):

```
targetSelect.val(optionIndex)
```

Comment: I thought I had the first suggestion before. LOL. Guess not. thanks. I'll mark this as correct once it's unlocked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <select class="form-control" name="gender" id="gender">
         <option value="M">Male</option>
         <option value="F">Female</option>
         <option value="T">Others</option>
</select>
      

$('#gender option[value="' +  obj.data.member_gender +'"]').prop("selected", true);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what does it provide that @ReGdYN's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67214507/7451109) didn't already?